# Is there any downside if I auto save a document continuously

Tags: pouchdb

Assuming I am running PouchDB locally, with replication triggered manually, is there any downside if I auto save a document continuously whenever a change is made? Or, is it better to auto save in a predefined time interval (with a check on whether changes has been made)?

Answer (score 0):

In broad general terms, these days in computing, yes, all text documents are continually saved (every keystroke/edit).

This is the case with every online system (google docs etc), every text editor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the document could be edited in more than one client, saving locally all the time could increase the chances of a replication conflict.

It also could introduce a penalty over time on your saves and replication since your document storage locally will get loaded with revisions and pouch doesn't always clean up after itself very well.